# BeautifulSoup 4 - Web scraping soccer matches for 'today'

Tags: python, html, css, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm very new to python and trying to webscrape soccer matches for 'today' from the fox sports website: https://www.foxsports.com/scores/soccer. Unfortunately, I keep running into issues with

> 'AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all''

and can't seem to get the teams for that day. This is what I have so far:

```
import bs4 
import requests 

res = requests.get('foxsports.com/scores/soccer') 
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser') 
results = soup.find("div", class_="scores-date") 
games = results.find("div", class_="scores") 

print(games)
```

Comment: You should check if res.text includes the website's content. It is probably the problem here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### What happens?

Content is not static it is served dynamically by website, so request won't get the information you can see in your dev tools.

#### How to fix?

Use an api provided or [`selenium`](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/upgrade_to_selenium_4/) that handels content like a browser and can provide the `page_source` you are looking for.

Cause not all of the content is provided directly, you have to use [selenium waits](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/) to locate the presence of the `<span>` with class "title-text".

#### Example

**Note** *Example uses [selenium 4](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/upgrade_to_selenium_4/), so check your version, update or adapt requiered dependencies to a lower version by yourself*

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

service = ChromeService(executable_path='ENTER YOUR PATH TO CHROMEDRIVER')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
driver.get('https://www.foxsports.com/scores/soccer')

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//span[contains(@class, "title-text") and text() = "Today"]')))

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

for g in soup.select('.scores-date:not(:has(div)) + div .score-chip-content'):
    print(list(g.stripped_strings))
```

#### Output

```
['SERIE A', 'JUVENTUS', '9-4-5', 'JUV', '9-4-5', 'CAGLIARI', '1-7-10', 'CAG', '1-7-10', '8:45PM', 'Paramount+', 'JUV -455', 'CAG +1100']
['LG CUP', 'ARSENAL', '0-0-0', 'ARS', '0-0-0', 'SUNDERLAND', '0-0-0', 'SUN', '0-0-0', '8:45PM', 'ARS -454', 'SUN +1243']
['LA LIGA', 'SEVILLA', '11-4-2', 'SEV', '11-4-2', 'BARCELONA', '7-6-4', 'BAR', '7-6-4', '9:30PM', 'ESPN+', 'SEV +155', 'BAR +180']
```

Comment: This is amazing. If you don't mind walking through some of the steps you did? I'm familiar with selenium but unfamiliar with the imports you made.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide a link with the http protocol. This code works:

```py
import bs4 
import requests 

res = requests.get('https://foxsports.com/scores/soccer') 
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser') 
results = soup.find("div", class_="scores-date") 
games = results.find("div", class_="scores") 
print(results)
print(games)
```

However, `games` is `None` because bs4 cannot find any div with class `scores` in `results`

Comment: There are elements in these tags, but for some reason I can't extract text from them.

Answer (score 0):

Far more efficient if you go through the api. All the data is there, including much more (but I only pulled out the scores to print out). You'll have to first access the site to grab the apikey to be used as a parameter.

I've also added the option to choose your group/league. So you'll nee to `pip install choice`

```
import requests
import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

#pip install choice
import choice

# Get the apikey
url = 'https://www.foxsports.com/scores/soccer'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
apikey = soup.find_all('div', {'data-scoreboard':re.compile("^https://")})[0]['data-scoreboard'].split('apikey=')[-1]


# Get the group Ids and correpsonding titles
url = 'https://api.foxsports.com/bifrost/v1/soccer/scoreboard/main'
payload = {'apikey':apikey}
jsonData = requests.get(url, params=payload).json()

groupsTitle_list = [ x['title'] for x in jsonData['groupList']]
groupsId_list = [ x['id'] for x in jsonData['groupList']]

groups_dict = dict(zip(groupsTitle_list, groupsId_list))

user_input = choice.Menu(groups_dict.keys()).ask()
groupId = groups_dict[user_input]


# Get the date of the score you are after
date_param = input('Enter date in YYYYMMDD format\nEx: 20220109\n-> ')
# If you prefer to always just grab todays score, use line below
#date_param = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d")


# Pull the score for the date and group
url = f'https://api.foxsports.com/bifrost/v1/soccer/scoreboard/segment/c{groupId}d{date_param}'
payload = {
    'apikey':apikey,
    'groupId':groupId}
jsonData = requests.get(url, params=payload).json()


if len(jsonData['sectionList']) == 0:
    print(f'No score available on {date_param} for {user_input}')

else:
    returnDate = jsonData['sectionList'][0]['menuTitle']
    print(f'\n {returnDate} - {user_input}')
    events = jsonData['sectionList'][0]['events']

    for event in events:
        lowerTeamName = event['lowerTeam']['longName']
        lowerTeamScore = event['lowerTeam']['score']
        
        upperTeamName = event['upperTeam']['longName']
        upperTeamScore =  event['upperTeam']['score']
        
        print(f'\t{upperTeamName} {upperTeamScore}')
        print(f'\t{lowerTeamName} {lowerTeamScore}\n')
```

**Output:**

```
Make a choice:
 0: FEATURED MATCHES
 1: ENGLISH PREMIER LEAGUE
 2: MLS
 3: LA LIGA
 4: LIGUE 1
 5: BUNDESLIGA
 6: UEFA CHAMPIONS LEAGUE
 7: LIGA MX
 8: SERIE A
 9: WCQ - CONCACAF

Enter number or name; return for next page

? 0


Enter date in YYYYMMDD format
Ex: 20220109
-> 20220109

 SUN, JAN 9 - FEATURED MATCHES
    LIVERPOOL 4
    SHREWSBURY 1

    TOTTENHAM 3
    MORECAMBE 1

    WOLVES 3
    SHEFFIELD UTD 0

    WEST HAM 2
    LEEDS UNITED 0

    NOTTINGHAM 1
    ARSENAL 0

    ROMA 3
    JUVENTUS 4

    LYON 1
    PARIS SG 1

    VILLARREAL 2
    ATLÉTICO MADRID 2

    GUADALAJARA 3
    MAZATLÁN FC 0
```